# .NET XmlDocument preserve whitespace

Tags: .net, xmldocument

I am parsing a XML document with XmlDocument. When the source file contains

```
<template>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <version>1</version>
  ABC
  DEF
  <author />
  ABC
```

I often need to get the pure underlying XML and I use `InnerXml` for this. But InnerXml discards all whitespace between two XML elements when there is only whitespace. Meaning the fragement above is as `InnerXml` not what you see above - instead it is:

```
<template><name>ABC</name><version>1</version>
  ABC
  DEF
  <author />
  ABC
```

How can I get the content of a `XmlNode` without the discarded whitespace? It must be somewhere in the XmlDocument because when saving it with `Save` it will output like loaded (meaning like the first example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you can just ask the XMlDocument to [PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) and you should get "WYSIWYG" loading/saving.

Comment: Sadly I was assuming this it true because `Save()` always gave my a nice formatting. But you are right, this influences `InnerXml` too. So solved, thank you!